# Using same code with multiple sub-domains

Tags: c#, asp.net, vs-web-site-project

I have a web project, which i am using for main domain (www.abc.com), now since my website is divided into 2 parts, i have added sub-domain (xyz.abc.com).

Now since both the site (main domain and sub-domain) has the same code except the homepage, i planned to publish my main-domain code into the sub-domain as well, but the problem is, in the web project, i have default.aspx (the home page for the main domain) and xyz.aspx (the homepage for the sub-domain).

Now if i publish the same code on both the sites, it will work fine on the main-domain, but on the sub-domain i will have to navigate to the webpage, xyz.abc.com/xyz.aspx.

Could anyone suggest how could i fix the issue, wherein, i don't have to do anything after publish and also i can access it directly at xyz.abc.com

Comment: If you are using IIS you could use URL Rewrite that redirects from default.aspx to xyz.aspx.

Comment: actually i would want the homepage to appear directly at xyz.abc.com without any further page navigation same for www.abc.com